# Function declaration in Golang

Tags: function, go

It seems there are two different ways to declare a function in Golang, like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"
var someFunc = func(arg string) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
func main() {
    someFunc("Hello")
}
```

The above works. However, the below does not work:

```
package main
import "fmt"
var someFunc = func(arg string) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
var main = func() {
    someFunc("Hello")
}
```

It will complain:

```
runtime.main: undefined: main.main
```

So what's the difference between `func someFunc()` and `var someFunc = func()`?

The reason I found this is probably because of I code a lot of Javascript, too. It seems in Go, I rarely see people declaring a function like `var someFunc=func()`. Of these two, can we say which one is more correct than the other one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you do

```
var someFunc = func(arg string) {}
```

you are assigning an anonymous function to the `somefunc` variable. You could also write it like this:

```
somefunc := func(arg string) {}
```

The other way to create a function is to create a named function:

```
func somefunc(arg string) {}
```

Named functions can only be declared at the top level whereas anonymous functions can be declared anywhere. And `main` has a special meaning, there has to be a named function called `main` in the `main` package, that's why you got an error in the second case.

Comment: Does `func somefunc(arg string){}` effectively create a `somefunc` variable? If this is the case, is there any significant difference between them?

Comment: No, it does not create a variable so they are different.

Comment: But I can do `fmt.Println(someFunc)` in both way. They both print out the memory address of the function. Is it not technically correct to call something you can pass to fmt.Println as a variable?

Comment: Here is what the spec has to say about [variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) and [function declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations). They are distinct but the distinction is small because functions are first-class data in Go.

Comment: You can assign a different function to `var f = func(){}` at runtime, but not to `func f(){}`. That means the compiler can inline `func f(){}` at compile time, since it knows `f` will always refer to the same function.

Answer (score 5):

```
func main() {
```

This is declaring a function named `main`.

```
var main = func() {
```

This is declaring an anonymous function and assigning it to a variable called main. Functions are first-class data in Go. You can assign the function itself to a variable.

Comment: Does `func somefunc(arg string){}` effectively create a `somefunc` variable? If this is the case, is there any significant difference between them?

Comment: No.  In the first case it would be an error to try and assign something else to `main`.  It would be okay in the second case.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [function declaration:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations)

```
func main() {}
```

This is a [variable declaration:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

```
var main = func() {}
```

The [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) says:

> "The main package must have package name main and declare a function
>   main that takes no arguments and returns no value."

A variable declaration isn't a function declaration and therefore doesn't meet the requirements for main.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because all functions have to be called inside the main function which is the starting point of your program.

Ex:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Print() {

    fmt.Println("Print function")
}

func main() {

    Print()

}
```