# golang: implicit vs explicit func definition

Tags: go

Consider this package:

```
package A
var X="change me"
var Y=func(i int) int { return i*i) }
func Z(i int) int { return -i) }
```

The two explicit variables (X,Y) can be changed in another package, say main...

```
package main
import "A"
func main () {
    A.X="done"
    A.Y=func (i int) int { return i*i*i }
    print(A.X,A.Y(7))
    //... but A.Z apparently can't be changed.
    //A.Z=func (int i) int { return i*i*i } //main.go:8: cannot assign to A.Z
}
```

Obviously there's a difference between defining a func variable (like Y) and an explicit func (like Z). I have googled this but not found much in the way of enlightenment. It almost seems as if var SomeFunc=func (...) defines indeed a variable, but func SomeFunc(...) defines a constant.

PS: A small goodie I found while researching this which I have not seen mentioned in the Go books I've read so far. A dot before a package import imports names without them having to be qualified:

```
package main
import . "A"
func main () {
    X="done"
    Y=func (i int) int { return i*i*i }
    print(X,Y(7))
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23925005/5419599, but that question has more answers.

Answer (score 3):

`func SomeFunc()`, in essence creates a strong/constant/immutable binding of the identifier `SomeFunc` to the function you define. When you create a variable like so:

```
var (
    SomeFunc = func(i int) int {
        return i * 2
    }
)
```

You create a global variable of the type `func(int) int`. You can reassign this variable later on. This is something you can't really do with a `func SomeFunc` identifier. Simply put, this is because `func SomeFunc()` binds the function *Directly* to the identifier. The `var SomeFunc` approach creates a variable (type `func(int) int` in this case), and that variable is initialised using the function you're assigning. As is the case with variables: reassignment is possible.

#### [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/QyFBtFGyQJ)

What you *can* do with functions, is shadow them using a scoped variable. This will probably get flagged by most linters, but it's a technique/trick that sometimes can be useful in testing

#### [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/OtfchIJ8w_)

As for the dot-imports: Please don't do that unless there's a very, very, *very* good reason for it. A good reason would be you writing a package that *adds* to an existing one, so you no longer import an existing one, but import your own. Think of it as *extending* a package. 99% of the time. Don't, whatever you do, use it to quench errors when you import `encoding/json` to add json serialization annotations to a struct. In those cases, use an underscore:

```
package foo
import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Bar struct {
    Foobar string `json:"foobar"`
}

func New() *Bar {
    &Bar{"Default foobar"}
}
```

Don't know about golang 1.8, but packages like that could result in compiler errors (package encoding/json imported but not used). To silence that error, you simply changed the import to:

```
import(
    _ "encoding/json"
)
```

The dot-packages, underscores, and package aliases all follow the same rule: use them as little as possible.

---

Code used in examples:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    SomeFunc = func(i int) int {
        return i * 2
    }
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeFunc(2)) // output 4
    reassign()
    fmt.Println(SomeFunc(2)) // output 8
    shadowReassign()
    fmt.Println(SomeFunc(2)) // output 2
}

// global function
func reassign() {
    // assign new function to the global var. Function types MUST match
    SomeFunc = func(i int) int {
        return i * 4
    }
}

// assign function to local reassign variable
func shadowReassign() {
    reassign := func() {
        // same as global reassign
        SomeFunc = func(i int) int {
            return i
        }
    }
    reassign()
}
```

Comment: Just a thought. It may be useful to add another call in main to reassign, then print to show that the original global still works and wasn't overwritten. Just for complete clarity.

Comment: @elias: so in effect what you're saying is that func SomeFunc(...) is indeed defining a constant, something like "const SomeFunc = func (...)". (This is not valid Go, I know.) I have not really seen an explanation of why that should be the case in the Go docs.  As to dot imports, I agree, this should be used sparingly though there are valid usage cases. I mentioned it because I had not seen it before (and I've read a lot about Go in the last couple weeks).

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @CharlesPerrin: One of the most important reasons for binding identifiers to a static function directly is quite simply: packages. If you export a function from a package, it's effectively read-only. Do the same thing with a variable and you'll end up with a package that can be altered by anyone (reassigning an exported variable). As for the previous comment: RayfenWindspear is, I believe, referring to shadowing the global variable

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between declaring a variable initialized with a function value:

```
var Y=func(i int) int { return i*i) }
```

and declaring a function:

```
 func Z(i int) int { return -i) }
```

The [specification says this about declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):

> A declaration binds a non-blank identifier to a constant, type, variable, function, label, or package.

The [specification also says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations):

> A function declaration binds an identifier, the function name, to a function.

The declaration of `Y` binds a variable to the name. This variable is initialized with a function value.  The declaration of `Z` binds a function to the name.

> If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the package's exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be declared in the importing source file's file block and must be accessed without a qualifier.